# Can't print label inside a picture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Although the form render as expected after Show(), when it's time to draw the image to the canvas the label seems to disappear when it's inside a picture whether it's a PictureBox or Label with a bg image.

Upon further checking it looks like the picture is being drawn at front even when I'm sending it to back. Any solutions?

[image: compare views]

```
  public partial class SampleForm: Form
{
    public SampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.BringToFront(); //plain label with bg color

        label2.SendToBack(); //label with a bg image
    }


    Bitmap original;
    Bitmap bitMaptoPrint;
    private void captureFromScreen()
    {
        
       original = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
       panel1.DrawToBitmap(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
       bitMaptoPrint = new Bitmap(original,new Size(816, 1056));
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle m = new Rectangle(0, 0, 816, 1056);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitMaptoPrint, m);
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captureFromScreen();
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

Comment: I do it in the Visual Studio GUI, so it doesn't show in code, but  because you said it I also try to do it in the constructor(view updated code) and it still does nothing.

Comment: Read the Remarks section of [Control.DrawToBitmap()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap) (second to last point)

Comment: Omg TY it's finally working!, just a little awkward as I have to always call sendToBack and bringToFront constantly. btw the problem seems to comefrom "Controls inside containers are rendered in reverse order." remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that DrawToBitmap() draw controls inside containers in reverse order. Solution is pretty straightforward just bring it to back, before every print.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picturebox1.sendToBack();
    captureFromScreen();
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to implement your `captureFromScreen()` method by *really* capturing the screen using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`. This way it should be *WYSIWYG* (helping avoid the "awkward" and constant shifting of the z-order you describe in your comment).

```
PrintPreviewDialog _printPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
private void captureFromScreen()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel.Width, panel.Height);
    var screenLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(screenLocation, Point.Empty, panel.Size);
    }

    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrintPage += localPrintPage;
    _printPreview.Document= document;

    _printPreview.ShowDialog();

    void localPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics?.DrawImage(
            bitmap,
                (e.PageBounds.Width - bitmap.Width) / 2,
                (e.PageBounds.Height - bitmap.Height) / 2,
                bitmap.Width,
                bitmap.Height);
    }
}
```

---

**Test**

[image: print preview]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);

        Label label = new Label
        {
            Name = "label1",
            Text = "Label",
            Location = new Point(0, panel.Height/2),
            Size = new Size(panel.Width, 80),
            BackColor= Color.FromArgb(231, 134, 131),
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        };
        panel.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(label, 0);
    }
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg.Equals(WM_KEYDOWN))
        {
            switch((Keys)m.WParam | ModifierKeys) 
            {
                case Keys.Control | Keys.P:
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> captureFromScreen()));
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```